# Use google drive api to upload MediaStream Recorder chunk to google drive?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I use MediaStream Recording API to record video.

How to continuously upload to google drive when MediaRecorder generates a video chunk??

It seems that Google Drive API can only upload files one by one?

[image]

ex.

```
MediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function(e) {

  // e.data is video chunk (blob)
  // How to upload to google drive
  console.log(e.data)

})
```

I tried many methods but all failed

I have referred to your article by tanaike

This is my code

My upload part is all stuck

```
fetch(videoResumableUrl,
            {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Length': blob.size,
                    'Content-Range': conter_range
                },
                // video chunk
                body: blob
            }
        ).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

[image]

```
let total = 0;
let start = 0;
let end = 0;
let endLock = true;
var videoResumableUrl = null;

async function createResumableUrl() {

    let response = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oAuth2Client.credentials.access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: 'videofile.webm',
            mimeType: 'video/webm'
        })
    })
    let fileid = await response.json()

    let resumableRes = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileid.id + '?uploadType=resumable', {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oAuth2Client.credentials.access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })

    videoResumableUrl = resumableRes.headers.get('Location')
}

createResumableUrl()

startBtn.onclick = () => {
    mediaRecorder.start(5000)
    //every 5 seconds create video chunk
}

stopBtn.onclick = () => {
    endLock = false
    mediaRecorder.stop()
}

// stream is my navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia promise callback stream
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=VP9', })

// recoder start Listener
// every 5 seconds create video chunk
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (e) => {

    // e.data is video blob chunk
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function () {

        total += blob.size

        let conter_range = ''

        if (!end)
            end += blob.size - 1
        else
            end += blob.size


        // recodering unknown total file size
        if (endLock) {
            conter_range = 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/*'
            console.log(conter_range)
        }

        // if my click stop btn i get total file size
        if (!endLock) {
            conter_range = 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total
            console.log(conter_range)
        }

        fetch(videoResumableUrl,
            {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Length': blob.size,
                    'Content-Range': conter_range
                },
                body: blob
            }
        ).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })

        start = end + 1
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)

})

// recoder stop Listener
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', (e) => {

})
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your Code and describe what the issue is with your code.

Comment: For example, when the file size is known (for example, at first, the maximum size is set and the remaining data is embeded by the silence data.), I thought that the resumable upload might be able to be used as a workaround. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable) But in the current stage, the resumable upload cannot be run with the asynchronous process. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132489107) So I'm not sure whether this is the better direction. I apologize for this.

Comment: How to implement the specific code recorded and uploaded in real time?

Comment: As @Tanaike mentioned, chunks cannot be currently uploaded asynchronously. I'd suggest you to star the FR Tanaike shared [Parallel Uploading Multiple Chunks for Resumable Upload](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132489107) in order to give it more visibility.